# Change the coordinate system in UIKit and/or CoreGraphics

Tags: ios, uikit, core-graphics, coordinates

Is it possible to change the origin of the coordinate system in the UIKit or CoreGraphics frameworks? I have attached a picture to explain what I mean:

Thanks![image]

Comment: I tried with transform, but subviews also rotate and I don't want it. I need rotate coordinate system only, if it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set a view's `transform`, it has two effects:

1. The view applies the transform to the graphics context used in `drawRect:`.
2. The view applies the transform to the coordinate system used to lay out its subviews.

From your comment it sounds like you want #1 but not #2.  Here are some ways you can get #1 without #2:

1. Don't set the view's `transform` at all.  Instead, apply the transform to the graphics context in `drawRect:`, like this:

   ```
   CGAffineTransform transform = ...
   CGContextConcatCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), transform);
   ```

   Or build up the transform directly in the graphics context using methods like `CGContextRotateCTM`.
2. Make a separate subview (with its own `UIView` subclass) for drawing, and set the transform on that subview.  Thus your view hierarchy will look like this:

   ```
   view
       subview for drawing, with transform
       other, untransformed subview #1
       other, untransformed subview #2
       other, untransformed subview #3
       etc.
   ```
3. Go to the view's underlying `CALayer`.  When you set the view's `transform` property, it converts the affine transform to a full 3D (4x4) transform matrix and sets the `transform` property of its layer.  The layer has another property, `sublayerTransform`, which applies only to its sublayers.  I believe you can set the `sublayerTransform` to the inverse of its `transform` to effectively make `transform` apply only to the graphics you draw into its context.  This should do it:

   ```
   view.transform = ...;
   view.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DInvert(view.layer.transform);
   ```

Comment: Hi. First solution doesn't work: CGContextRotateCTM(ctx, -M_PI_2); Another two solutions have strange effects. Any other solution? Thanks!

Comment: Finally!!    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect));
        CGContextRotateCTM(ctx, DegToRad(-90));
        CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, -CGRectGetMidX(rect), -CGRectGetMidY(rect));